# CDATA format string convert with MimeKit

Tags: c#, converters, mimekit

I have string data as CDATA Format. How can I convert this to Html or normal view text at C#? Should I use mimeKit or something else?

> ```
> Received: from 172.19.76.148 (proxying for 85.105.234.193)
>   (InterKepWebMail authenticated user parkentegrasyon)
>   by kep.local with HTTP;
>   Mon, 29 Jan 2018 18:51:40 +0300
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary="------_=_NextPart_001_01F869E9.0A514C28"
> Message-ID: <8ec68378-eca0-428d-a350-94427435a521.webmail@testkep.inter-kep.com.tr>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 18:51:40 +0300
> From: "parkentegrasyon" <parkentegrasyon@testkep.inter-kep.com.tr>
> To: <parkentegrasyon@testkep.inter-kep.com.tr>
> Cc: <parkentegrasyon@testkep.inter-kep.com.tr>
> Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=C3=96rnek_KEP_2018-01-29_18=3A51=3A41?=
> User-Agent: InterKepWebMail/1.0.0
> X-TR-REM-iletiTip: standart
> X-TR-REM-iletiID: 
>
> --------_=_NextPart_001_01F869E9.0A514C28
> Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset="utf-8"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> <b>Merhaba D=C3=BCnya!</b>
> --------_=_NextPart_001_01F869E9.0A514C28
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
>   name="test.txt"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
> Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="test.txt"
>
> dGVzdCBlaw==
>
> --------_=_NextPart_001_01F869E9.0A514C28--
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MimeKit to parse the message, it will automatically decode the content (whether it be in base64 or quoted-printable).

In your example message, the `text/html` message body can be gotten like this:

```
var html = message.HtmlBody;
```

To get the decoded attachment content, you can do this:

```
foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments.OfType<MimePart> ()) {
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream ()) {
        attachment.Content.DecodeTo (memory);

        var data = memory.ToArray ();
        var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's base64 encoded text. You can decode it like this

```
      byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String("dGVzdCBlaw==");
      string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
      Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
```

That prints 'Test ek'.

Comment: Thank you but I try this and it say it's not a base64 .